# How to handle sensitive data, and pass it to a function?

Tags: powershell, encryption

I have some parameters that are stored in an encrypted text-file on a local hard disk. These parameters must stay secret.

How to read/decrypt the parameters from the file and pass them to a powershell function, in a way that the variables are never exposed / in plain text?

I would like to use secure-strings, but how to pass them to a powershell function? This I tried:

```
function Create-Securestring
{
    $my_secure_password = convertto-securestring "password" -asplaintext -force
    return $my_secure_password

}

function Accept-Securestring
{
    param($secure)  
    $cast = [string]$secure ## maybe cast works?
    $test = "$cast test string"
    if ($secure -eq "password"){ write "works fine" }
    return $test
}


$secure = Create-Securestring
$test = Accept-Securestring $secure
$test # -> System.Security.SecureString test string
```

I give here an example of an external file, but any method to store and use secret data as described above is accepted.

Comment: How do you expect to be able to work with the data without decrypting it? And if you're not working with it: why bother loading it in the first place?

Comment: Yes, decrypt and convert to securestring.

Comment: Plenty examples of storing (and restoring) `SecureString` values in files exist online (and on this site). What is the actual question here? What are you having troubles with?

Comment: How are the data encrypted? Besides, you do realize that secure strings [aren't as secure as one would expect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30653815/1630171), don't you?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen. One can pass a securestring to an application yes. But not to a powershell-function..at least I can't.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers No I didnt realize. Makes the question only more relevant.

Comment: Of course you can pass a `SecureString` object to a PowerShell function. If it doesn't work for you: please show your code and any error you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue was with converting a secure string back to a regular string. You could turn it into a `PScredential` and use `GetNetworkCredential().Password` like Ansgar linked or you could use some methods from `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]`.

```
function Create-Securestring {
    convertto-securestring "password" -asplaintext -force
}

function Accept-Securestring {
    $secure = Create-Securestring
    $BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secure)            
    $cast = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
    "$cast test string"
    if ($cast -eq "password"){ write "works fine" }
}
```

But note that converting them back is making them into "plaintext". Which brings you back to Ansgar's point in the first comment, if it's supposed to be secure now you making it unsecure.

Comment: It's because of this problem I asked this question.

Comment: @joops Let me rephrase my first comment to your question: you MUST decrypt your data before you can actually work with them. Meaning your data WILL be unencrypted at some point. There is no way around this.

Comment: How about passing a `securestring`to `PSCredential object`? Like: `  $MyCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
 -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)   `  ?

Comment: @joops That's functionally equivalent to this.

Comment: So decrypt and convert to plaintext and than dispose the plaintext variable immediately after use is the best thing I can do?

Comment: @joops Yes, if you want to work with the contents of the variable it has to be decrypted somehow. If you can decrypt then dispose, that works. If you still need to use it, you could decrypt then make a [salted hash](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Script-410ef9df).